# Заполнение матрицы в спиральном режиме

Tags: c++, матрицы

задача:

> написать программу, которая будет заполнять матрицу NxN нулями и единицами в спиральном режиме (начиная с левого верхнего угла, посмотрите на пример).

> Ввод
> Одна строка содержит только одно нечетное число N (1 <= N <= 50)

> Выход
> Выведите матрицу с нулями и единицами, расположенную по спирали.

Образцы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int n, m = 1;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n][n];
    
    if(n % 2 != 0){
        a[(n / 2)][(n / 2)] = (n * n);      // если N - нечетное то находим центр матрицы и заполняем его числом N * N
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < (n / 2); i++){
        for(int j = i; j < (n - i); j++){   // (n - i) - чтоб с каждым разом сторона становилась меньше
            a[i][j] = m;
            m++;
        }
        for(int j = 1; j < (n - i - i); j++){   // начинаем с первого эл. так-как нулевой уже записан
            a[(j + i)][(n - i) - 1] = m;    // (n - i) - 1 - отнимаем 1 чтоб не выходило за рамки массива
            m++;
        }
        for(int j = (n - 2) - i; j >= i; j--){  // (n - 2) - i - отнимаем 1 чтоб не выходило за рамки массива и еще одну 1 
            a[(n - i) - 1][(j)] = m;            // потому-что предыдущий эл. уже заполнен.
            m++;
        }
        for(int j = ((n - i) - 2); j > i; j--){
            a[j][i] = m;
            m++;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++){
            cout << a[i][j] << " " ;
        }
        cout << a[i][n - 1] << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

проблема в том что надо вывести код как на картинке, а выходит так

```
2 3 4 5 6 7
24 25 26 27 28 29 8
23 40 41 42 43 30 9
22 39 48 49 44 31 10
21 38 47 46 45 32 11
20 37 36 35 34 33 12
19 18 17 16 15 14 13
```

Comment: Я дал вам ответ если он вам помог, то примите его, если нет то скажите что ни так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int matrix[size][size];
        
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
        
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2){
        
        for (int j = i - 1; j < size - i; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = 1;
        }
    
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size - i; j++){
            matrix[j][size - i - 1] = 1;        
        }
        
        for (int j = i; j < size - i - 1; j++){
            matrix[size - i - 1][j]= 1;
        }
        
        for (int j = i + 2; j < size - i; j++){
            matrix[j][i]= 1;
        }
    }
        
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
}
```